# How to get the Command line argument to read output from another method in the same c program files?

Tags: c, methods, command-line-arguments, argv, argc

```
            /*Populate the int array mahRands with random numbers using a function which
        you then invoke from the main method.
        */
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        
        // use rand() % some_number to generate a random number
        void functionRan(){
            int i;
            int mahRands[3];
            for(i = 0;i < 3; i++){
                mahRands[i] = rand() % 200;
                printf("%d ",mahRands[i]);
                }
        }
        //command line argument
        int main(int argc, char *argv[])
        /*argc (argument count) and argv (argument vector)
        argc is the number of things `enter code here`in the command line 
        argv is an array that hold the char values that where entered*/
        {
            //functionRan();
            int i;
            for(i =0; i< argc; i++){
                printf("\nargv[%d] = %d",i,argv[i]);// argv[0] = 41;
            }
         return 0;
         
        }
```

> My output is argv[0] = 6628720
> I want main "the command line argument" to read functionRan and set the arraylength and its values to argc and argv".there should be 3 outputs. The numbers are generated random.
> argv[0] = 66
> argv[1] = 26
> argv[2] = 87

Comment: `argv` are **inputs** to `main`. You aren't really supposed to be changing those. If you want `functionRan` to pass values back to `main` in an array then define `functionRan` to take an array arg: `void functionRan(int *array, int num_elements)` and then call it in `main` like this: `int array[3]; functionRan(array, sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[3])));`

Comment: This is all very basic C - defining functions and passing args to functions. If that is not understandable to you then that's ok but it would benefit you to pause programming and review a good C book or tutorial before continuing on.

Comment: From the commented-out `argv[0] = 41;` you can't overwrite the pointer at `argv[0]` with such a value without making trouble, and it is pointless: `argv[0]` informs the code what the executable's name is and it makes no sense to (try to) change it. In any case, `argv[n]` points to a *string*. It is not an integer.